# How many pesukim are there that have two (or more) etnachta clauses?

Tags: trop-cantillation

The Pasuk Bereshit 35:22 carries two entachta clauses and a pasuk break without a sof pasuk Trope. Are there other pesukim with
a) two or more etnachta clauses?
b) a paska within the pasuk, i.e. with teh text breaking to a new line without a sof pasuk trope sign?

If so I would be very interested to know which pasuks these were.

Answer (score 8):

There are no verses with more than one Etnachta. Even your example is not one. There are two "traditions" for how to read that section. One version has all of what we call 35:22 as one verse, and accordingly marks it with a section-break in the middle like this:

> וַיְהִ֗י בִּשְׁכֹּ֤ן יִשְׂרָאֵל֙ בָּאָ֣רֶץ הַהִ֔וא וַיֵּ֣לֶךְ רְאוּבֵ֗ן וַיִּשְׁכַּב֙ אֶת־בִּלְהָה֙ פִּילֶ֣גֶשׁ אָבִ֔יו וַיִּשְׁמַ֖ע יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל {פ}
> וַיִּֽהְי֥וּ בְנֵֽי־יַעֲקֹ֖ב שְׁנֵ֥ים עָשָֽׂר

The other version has what we call 35:22 as two seperate verses with a section break between them like this:

> וַיְהִ֗י בִּשְׁכֹּ֤ן יִשְׂרָאֵל֙ בָּאָ֣רֶץ הַהִ֔וא וַיֵּ֣לֶךְ רְאוּבֵ֔ן וַיִּשְׁכַּ֕ב אֶת־בִּלְהָ֖ה פִּילֶ֣גֶשׁ אָבִ֑יו וַיִּשְׁמַ֖ע יִשְׂרָאֵֽל׃ {פ}
> וַיִּֽהְי֥וּ בְנֵֽי־יַעֲקֹ֖ב שְׁנֵ֥ים עָשָֽׂר

Printers sometimes put both sets of dots on all the words which probably led to your confusion. (Also, by convention we number the verses in accordance with the first version.)

There are a handful of examples of section breaks in the middle of verses (eg. Numbers 26:1, Deuteronomy 2:8).

Comment: Tip: you might be more familiar with the notion of two sets of trop from the other more famous place it happens, the 10 Commandments.